# How to hide Credit Card Payment Method on Magento with Onepage Checkout enable?

Tags: php, magento, paypal, payment

I want to keep Onepage Checkout enable (YES), but just one to offer the standar on Paypal site payment. By default once Onepage Checkout is activated, Payment page will show the Credit Card option.

**My question is**: How to hide the Credit Card Payment Option even with Onepage Checkout enable, just to offer Paypal site payment (standar) ??

My engine is Magento 1.7.0.2. Please let me know files and codes to change. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Goto->magento admin->system->configuration->sales->payment methods->saved cc -> enabled (select no)

Answer (score 0):

In Magento admin

System > Sales >Payment Methods > Saved CC > (Enable = NO)